# Define coordinate based on other coordinate in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

Can I define a coordinate relative to an already defined coordinate? If I define a coordinate **(A)** with

```
\coordinate (A) at (2,0);
```

Is there a way to define a coordinate **(B)** that is 2cm to the left and one 1cm to the top of **(A)**? I am looking for something like:

```
\coordinate (B) at (A+(2cm,1cm));
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

with `calc` library, you can add coordinates

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc} % in the preamble
...
\coordinate (B) at ($(A)+(2cm,1cm)$);
```

or with positioning library

```
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} % in the preamble
...
\coordinate[above right=1cm and 2cm of A] (B);
```

Comment: or with a shift: `\coordinate (B) at ([shift={(2cm,1cm)}]A);`

Comment: or `\path (A) ++(2cm,1cm) coordinate (B);`.